# kable not printing something that looks like a table

Tags: r, r-markdown, kable, kableextra

[image]

My kables are printing as shown in the image instead of in a table format

I was playing around with kable and it was printing things out the way you'd expect as a table. However, somewhere along the way, all of the kable I tried to print appeared the way as shown in the picture. I'm using a .Rmd file if that makes a difference. I've tried searching online about this, but I couldn't find anything on it.

My session info:

```
devtools::session_info('rmarkdown')
─ Session info ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 setting  value
 version  R version 4.2.3 (2023-03-15 ucrt)
 os       Windows 10 x64 (build 19045)
 system   x86_64, mingw32
 ui       RStudio
 language (EN)
 collate  English_United States.utf8
 ctype    English_United States.utf8
 tz       America/Los_Angeles
 date     2023-04-12
 rstudio  2023.03.0+386 Cherry Blossom (desktop)
 pandoc   2.19.2 @ C:/Program Files/RStudio/resources/app/bin/quarto/bin/tools/ (via rmarkdown)

─ Packages ─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
 package   * version date (UTC) lib source
 base64enc   0.1-3   2015-07-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 bslib       0.4.2   2022-12-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 cachem      1.0.7   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 cli         3.6.0   2023-01-09 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 digest      0.6.31  2022-12-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 ellipsis    0.3.2   2021-04-29 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 evaluate    0.20    2023-01-17 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 fastmap     1.1.1   2023-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 fs          1.6.1   2023-02-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 glue        1.6.2   2022-02-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 highr       0.10    2022-12-22 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 htmltools   0.5.4   2022-12-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 jquerylib   0.1.4   2021-04-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 jsonlite    1.8.4   2022-12-06 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 knitr     * 1.42    2023-01-25 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 lifecycle   1.0.3   2022-10-07 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 magrittr    2.0.3   2022-03-30 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 memoise     2.0.1   2021-11-26 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 mime        0.12    2021-09-28 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.0)
 R6          2.5.1   2021-08-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rappdirs    0.3.3   2021-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rlang       1.1.0   2023-03-14 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 rmarkdown   2.20    2023-01-19 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 sass        0.4.5   2023-01-24 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 stringi     1.7.12  2023-01-11 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 stringr   * 1.5.0   2022-12-02 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 tinytex     0.44    2023-02-01 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 vctrs       0.6.0   2023-03-16 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 xfun        0.37    2023-01-31 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)
 yaml        2.3.7   2023-01-23 [1] CRAN (R 4.2.2)

 [1] C:/Users/yongl/AppData/Local/R/win-library/4.2
 [2] C:/Program Files/R/R-4.2.3/library
```

Comment: The HTML code for the table is printing to the console because you're using `print()`. If you want to see the table omit `print()` and just use `kable(mtcars)`.

Comment: @neilfws Thanks for your answer, I can see the table beneath the code chunk when I only use 'kable(mtcars)' in a code chunk. Does the weird formatting happen to kable in general when it's printed to the console? It showed up as a table at the start when I was printing to the console for some reason.